# How to configure proxy for springboot and mediawiki?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, proxy, mediawiki

Currently I'm trying to run both SpringBoot application and mediawiki server (but I assume it may be any other server) on one machine simultaniously. They are both accessed via different ports e.g. 8080 and 7734.

Now I want to be able to access my Spring app as usual on `localhost:8080/homePage` and if I type something like this (with wiki included in the beggining of the url) `localhost:8080/wiki/faqPage` there must be some setting (or maybe another proxy server?) to redirect requests to the mediawiki instance. So the request to `localhost:8080/wiki/faqPage` would actually go to `localhost:7734/faqPage`. What is the best practice for achieving this?

If it helps I'm using docker image and docker-compose util to run mediawiki instance

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Apache's ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in the httpd.conf did the magic